# presentModalViewController in landscape

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation, landscape

I've searched this forum (and others) but haven't found a solution yet.
I have a app in landscape mode. Everythin fine, but when I change to another view (with a UITable) its in portrait mode and doesnt rotate. I have tried whole day but cant figure it out.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *aView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIViewController *aViewcontroller;
-----
aViewcontroller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
aViewcontroller.view = aView;
-----
[self presentModalViewController:aViewcontroller animated:YES];
//got my view in portrait orientation.
```

My views in my .xib file are all set to Orientation:Landscape.
This should be simple, right?

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default UIViewController supports only Portrait orientation. In order to support other orientations you need create new custom view controller which supports the orientations you need.

Steps:

Create new custom view controller `ViewControllerLandscape`

Then import it to your mainn view controller

```
#import "ViewControllerLandscape.h"
```

Change your code:

```
aViewcontroller = [[ViewControllerLandscape alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
aViewcontroller.view = aView;
[self presentModalViewController:aViewcontroller animated:YES];
```

in your `ViewControllerLandscape` add the method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
      (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))  {   
       return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You need to put it in aViewcontroller.m

Comment: Also add it to your main view controller + in Targets->Summary set Supported Device Orientations

Comment: I havent got a aViewController.m file. \n I create the viewcontrollers  in ViewController.h & m... isnt this the correct way?

Comment: I got your problem. You should create customViewController and add the code i wrot in the answer to this controller. I adited the answer

Comment: I'm sorry but how do you create a customViewController? file-new-view gives me a xib file. (i'm a starter)..

Comment: NewFile...->CocoaTouch->Objectiv-C class->add your name for the class+select view controller you want to override. P.S. xib file (is used to create the view) ViewController.m is used to fill the view with the content.

Comment: Super! made a new testproject and it works fine. Should be working if I implement this. very thanks. Thanks for the clear explanation, I get it.